# how to focus the scroll based on the current selection class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

am trying to focus the scroll based on the selected add class,when clicking on the previous and next button the scroll need to focus it. how can i make it possible please check my fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/kannankds/bcszkqLu/

```
<ul class="kds">
<li>tile dtls1</li>
<li>tile dtls2</li>
<li>tile dtls3</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="previous" class="previous">
<input type="button" value="next" class="next">
```

Comment: Are you trying to move the elements or the selection?

Comment: @ Rejith R Krishnan  selection need to visible always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
$(".kds").scrollTop(($(".currentSelection").index()-2) * $(".currentSelection").outerHeight());
```

for `previous` and

```
$(".kds").scrollTop($(".currentSelection").index() * $(".currentSelection").outerHeight());
```

for `next`

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bcszkqLu/4/)

Comment: @Ryan.Hunt   thats it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can animate your scroll using `scrollTop` like:

```
$('.kds').animate({'scrollTop' : (current.index()) * 30},1000);
```

Here 30 because your li height + padding top + padding bottom .

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcszkqLu/5/)**